# How to evenly assign workloads (criteria: must be present, unique case)?

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for ways on how to evenly assign workloads to employees who are present, and also ensuring that cases are unique per employee.

I have a spreadsheet I export containing a list of invoices defined per line item (showing same companies multiple times, etc). I then need to assign companies unique per employee who are present, without having duplicate companies. So far, my code is able to determine:

1. How many companies are in the sheet
2. How many invoices each company has
3. How many employees are present
4. How the division of allocation should be done

I am stuck at step 4 because there are instances where the distribution = 34, for example, but one company will have > 34 invoices. How can I go about this so the allocations are close to the computed distribution as possible. Sharing with you below the code I have created:

```
Sub allocation()
 exportFile.Range("E:E").Copy dataPrep.Range("B:"B)
 dataPrep.Range("A1:C" & countRows(dataPrep,"B")).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
 dim carrierExp as Range
 dim carrierData as Range
 Set carrierExp = exportFile.Range("E2:E" & countRows(exportFile, "E"))
 Set carrierData = dataPrep.Range("B2:B" & countRows(dataPrep, "B"))

 For Each carrier In carrierData
  carrier.Offset(0,1).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(carrierExp, carrier)
 Next

 Dim sumWL, distribWL, presentEmp as Long
 Dim presentRoster as Range

 sumWL = WorksheetFunction.Sum(dataPrep.Range("C2:C" & countRows(dataPrep, "C")))
 Set presentRoster = roster.Range("D2:D" & countRows(roster, "D"))
 presentEmp = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(presentRoster, "Y")
 distribWL = sumWL / presentEmp

End Sub
```

After running this program, I encountered the distribution to be 34, but one of the companies had 38 invoices.

Comment: Have you set this up on a sheet and tried the Solver?

Comment: Which column on roster are the employee names ?